# how to get a release without getting warn?

Tags: android, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I have problem  with compiling my app. problem is I get these problems and I don't know how to solve it. thanks all of you.

how can i solve it?
how can i set these warn in proguard without getting problems in my code?
or how can i compile without obfuscate these warn?

the below codes are warns which are shown in my messages:

```
class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpInetConnection
    Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpConnection
    Warning:library class com.android.internal.http.multipart.MultipartEntity extends or implements program class org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.auth.AuthenticationException extends or implements program class org.apache.http.ProtocolException
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.auth.MalformedChallengeException extends or implements program class org.apache.http.ProtocolException
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.auth.params.AuthParamBean extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.HttpAbstractParamBean
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException extends or implements program class org.apache.http.ProtocolException
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.RedirectException extends or implements program class org.apache.http.ProtocolException
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity extends or implements program class org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase extends or implements program class org.apache.http.message.AbstractHttpMessage
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.params.AllClientPNames extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.CoreConnectionPNames
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.params.AllClientPNames extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.params.ClientParamBean extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.HttpAbstractParamBean
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestDefaultHeaders extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestTargetAuthentication extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpResponseInterceptor
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity extends or implements program class org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.ManagedClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpClientConnection
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.ManagedClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpInetConnection
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.OperatedClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpClientConnection
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.OperatedClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpInetConnection
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnConnectionParamBean extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.HttpAbstractParamBean
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnManagerParamBean extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.HttpAbstractParamBean
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnRouteParamBean extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.HttpAbstractParamBean
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.cookie.MalformedCookieException extends or implements program class org.apache.http.ProtocolException
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.cookie.params.CookieSpecParamBean extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.HttpAbstractParamBean
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.ClientParamsStack extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.AbstractHttpParams
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.RequestWrapper extends or implements program class org.apache.http.message.AbstractHttpMessage
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.TunnelRefusedException extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpException
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser extends or implements program class org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionInputBuffer extends or implements program class org.apache.http.io.SessionInputBuffer
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer extends or implements program class org.apache.http.io.SessionOutputBuffer
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory
    Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
    Warning:za.co.riggaroo.materialhelptutorial.MaterialTutorialFragment: can't find referenced method 'com.bumptech.glide.DrawableTypeRequest load(java.lang.Integer)' in program class com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager
    Warning:za.co.riggaroo.materialhelptutorial.MaterialTutorialFragment: can't find referenced class com.bumptech.glide.DrawableTypeRequest
    Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
    Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
    Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
    Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
    Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
    Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
    Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
    Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
    Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
    Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
    Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
    Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
    Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
    Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
    Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
    Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
    Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
    Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
    Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
    Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpOptions depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase depends on program class org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase depends on program class org.apache.http.RequestLine
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.ConnectionReuseStrategy
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.ConnectionReuseStrategy
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponseInterceptor
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.ConnectionReuseStrategy
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpProcessor
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.ConnectionReuseStrategy
    Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor
    Warning:there were 15 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
    Warning:there were 132 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
    Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
    Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `DefaultHttpClient` since apache libraries are not available on Android 6.0+. See more at [Android 6.0 changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

Comment: I have used  library: useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'